# Start a php code (competition in which some users are) for users, logged in or not

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok I know the title doesn't really tell you what my problem is but I'll try it now.
I am developing a game. People can subscribe their animals for a race. That race starts at a specific time. It is a race for which ALL users can subscribe. So the calculation of which animal is first, second etc. happens in an php file that is executed, every 2mins there is a new calculation for about 1h. So there are 30 calculations. But ofc. this code is not connected to the logged in user. The logged in user can click on the LIVE button to see the current result.

Example: There is a race at 17.00 later today. 15 animals subscribed, from 4 players and they can all check how their animals are doing.

I do not want someone to post me the full code but I want to know how I should let a php code run for about 1 hour (so execute code, sleep 2min, new calculation, sleep 2min and so on) on my server or so. So it is not connected to the user.

I thought about cron jobs but that is really not the solution for this I believe.
Thank you for reading :p

Comment: why is cron not the solution? sounds ideal to me...

Comment: Someone told me that executing a php code through cron jobs is not the thing to do. So I should use cron jobs then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. You use an algorithm which will always come to the same conclusion, regardless of when it is run and who runs it. You just define the starting parameters, then at any time you can calculate the result (or the intermediate result at any point in time between start and finish) when needed. So any user can at any time visit your site and the algorithm will calculate the current standings on the fly from some fixed starting condition.
2. Alternatively, you keep all data in a central data store and actually update the data in certain intervals; any user can request the current standings at any time and the latest data from the datastore will be used. You will still need an algorithm that has traits of the one described above, since you're likely explicitly *not* actually running the simulation in real time. Just every x seconds, you run your calculations again, calculating what is supposed to have changed from the last time you ran them.

In essence, *any* algorithm you use needs this approach. Even a "realtime" program simply keeps looping, changing values little by little from their previous state. The interval between theses changes can be arbitrarily stretched out, to the point where you calculate nothing until it becomes necessary. In the meantime, you just store all the data you need in a database.

Comment: I will have to reread this a few times but Thank you for the answer!
So do you suggest that I use cron jobs?
The thing is that with every calculation the results table in my database is updated. Can I update that every 2mins with sleep or is there another way to do this more efficient?

Comment: Yes, you *can* do it with a cron job every 2 mins. But again, if you do it every 2 mins, why not every 5 mins? Why not every 60 mins? Why not only when a user requests to see the latest status? It's up to you, only the tradeoffs are different. Calculating more often takes more server resources but is a more constant load. Calculating only when needed may be more efficient. Calculating in regular intervals means the data will be old for some amount of time, calculating every time it's needed means it's more accurate, but may be too resource intensive. Find the best balance for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive explanation, I think I get it!

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are the wright way i think. Check this out when you are not so good with algorithm:[How To: PHP with Cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/) Maybe you have to use different cron jobs.

Comment: Already looked at that, but thanks anyway :D
It was more a question about what would be the best thing to do for me, not how to do it :p